# I want make join 2 tables but on 2 things not the typical same, like slug and path , slug abc , and path /article

Tags: python, sql, database, psql

I have 2 tables one name log contains (path, and log id, etc)
second table name articles contain (slug, id, title)

I want to make a query make join on articles.slug on a log. path

(the problem there path = /articles/slug)

how I make this join

I found pattern called '% %' I tried to use it in join but I don't know how like join on log.path = '/article/' + log.slug

```
  log.path                       log.count(path)view  article.slug   
-------------------------------------+- -------|--------------------
/                                   | 479121  |   
/article/candidate-is-jerk          | 338647  |   candidate-is-jerk
/article/bears-love-berries         | 253801  |   bears-love-berries
/article/bad-things-gone            | 170098  |   bad-things-gone
```

I need make join on this log.path = '/article/' + log.slug

Comment: What database are you using?  "psql" suggests Postgres, but I'm not sure if that is your intention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can express this `join` in SQL as:

```
from log l join
     article a
     on l.path = concat('/article/', a.slug);
```

or (using standard syntax):

```
from log l join
     article a
     on l.path = '/article/' || a.slug;
```

The second form will handle `null` values, by ignoring them.  The first will (generally but it might depend on the database) return `null` if either value is null.

Answer (score 0):

You can do join like this

```
on log.path like concat('%article%',article.slug);
```